# Is fast shutdown/startup ok for restarts for installations

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, installation, shutdown

I'm trying to install some applications and update some applications that require a restart to be fully installed/updated. I have fast startup enabled, I believe. If I just shut it down, then turn it on again with fast startup enabled, is that enough to fully install the application, or do I need to do a full/normal restart in order for it to work properly?

Comment: Yes; because Windows is reloaded

Comment: Yes, it will work, or yes, I need to do a full restart?

Comment: Yes; a fast restart or shutdown results in system files to be reloaded